# Exchange 2003: new user name could not be resolved

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook

I create a new user on our SBS 2003 with Exchange 2003.
The setup went well, the new user can logon, also the exchange setup has worked - access to the mailbox over OWA is working.

Now I'm setting up the user's Win XP computer. Starting and setting up Outlook 2003 with the exchange server name and new username, I'am getting the error

> The name could not be resolved. The name could not be matched to a name in the address list.

If I use the username of another, previously existing user, the name resolves correctly. This means that the communication from PC to Exchange server is working OK (DNS etc).

On the server, the new user appears correctly in `Active Directory Users and Computers`.

Do I need to "publish" the new user somehow?

What should I do, so that outlook finds the exchange mailbox?

Comment: The error means exactly what it states, the name can't be matched to a name in the address list. Preview the address list in ESM and make sure the user shows up. Also make sure the user is not hidden from the address list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user joeqwerty for the tip. I checked the global address list and in fact the user was not listed.

In the AD User Properties, on the organization tab, I had to complete the "Company" field (which was needed in the one global address list filter).